# Is it possible to use monotouch uikit in xamarin ui tests

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I am currently writing ui tests and I would like to be able to check things like if the TableViewCell has been selected or not. I see in the monotouch uikit there is a Selected method listed. I have tried to use it but got no results(see code below). Does anyone know how this can be used for UI testing?:

```
app.Query(e => e.Class("UITableViewCell.Selected"));
app.Query(e => e.Class("UITableViewCell").Selected);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke the `ObjC` name instead of the C# one.

So for `UITableViewCell`, the selected method is `isSelected` with zero parameters.

re: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623263-isselected

In your test, you can use `Invoke` something like:

```
app.Query(e => e.Id("IdTestCell").Class("UITableViewCell").Invoke("isSelected", 0).Value<bool>());
```

Results in:

```
Query for Id("IdTestCell").Class("UITableViewCell").Invoke("isSelected", 0).Value<Boolean>() gave 1 results.
[                                                                                                                                
   [0] true                                                                                                             
]
```

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover